# SuSE tells my password is based on a dictionary word

Tags: linux, passwords

I'm installing SuSE 13.2 and when typing the initial password, it tells me it is too simple and based on a dictionary word. Where can I check this dictionary on my Linux system?

Comment: Can you provide the exact notification message?

Comment: Not the exact wording (I proceeded though the warning), but it was something along "Your password is too simple. It is based on a dictionary word".

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to know what the exact wording of the notification message was.  Should be easy enough to replicate the problem in order to provide this very helpful information.

Comment: [This](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/bad-password-it-is-based-on-a-dictionary-word-449149/) seems to indicate you enabled the `pam_pwcheck` module enabled.  It seems the configuration is located at `/etc/security/pam_pwcheck`

Comment: Is there a way to make the dictionary human readable, so I can verify whether my password is already part of such a dictionary?

Comment: Here is the [text version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cracklib/files/) of the dictionary at the project page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cracklib-unpacker /usr/share/cracklib/pw_dict >full-list.txt
```

gives you the full list. After modifying the text file, for example

```
grep -v thomas full-list.txt >modified-list.txt
```

you can create a new dictionary with

```
create-cracklib-dict modified-list.txt
```

Now you can use your name 'thomas' as part of your password.

(Strangely, on OpenSUSE Leap 42.1, verifying the changes running the unpacker again shoes that words with 30 characters are also removed.)

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary is compiled in, most likely not available in a human readable format.

The following should tell you how to add to the existing dictionary if available to your system.

```
man create-cracklib-dict
```

You can manually check a list of words against the dictionary using cracklib. The following should tell you how:

```
man cracklib-check
```